# Classification in R using Naive Bayes

Tags: naivebayes

I would like to know how to implement Naive Bayes classifier in R.
I am stuck at the following :
How to split data file into training and test data if file is in csv format, has 8 variables and more than 700 rows.

Comment: I tried to use splitDataPartition but unable to use it as it says unknown.

Comment: I am confused in translating Naive Bayes classifier into programme